# How to get current frame of currently playing video file?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, video, mxml

So we have flv file, we play it with mx:vidodisplay for example. how to get on which stream frame we are currently on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check the nearest keyframe to the current time in stream metadata
**upd**
when creating a stream you need to handle its' `onMetaData` call:

```
private var metaInfo: Object;
```

```
private function initStream():void{
     stream = new NetStream(conn);
     stream.bufferTime = 5;            
     stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatus);
     stream.client = new Object();
     stream.client.onMetaData = onMetaData;/*this is what you need*/
     video.attachNetStream(stream);
}
private function onMetaData(info:Object):void {
    metaInfo = info;
    var tmpstr:String = '';
    for(var s:String in info){
       var tstr:String = s + ' = ' + info[s] + '\n';
       tmpstr += tstr.indexOf('object') == -1 ? tstr : '';
       for(var a:String in info[s]){
           var ttstr:String = s + ':' + a + ' = ' + info[s][a] + '\n';
           tmpstr += ttstr.indexOf('object') == -1 ? ttstr : '';
            for(var c:String in info[s][a]){
                var tttstr:String = s + ':' + a + ':' + c + ' = ' + info[s][a][c] + '\n';
                tmpstr += tttstr.indexOf('object') == -1 ? tttstr : '';                     
            }
        }
    }
    trace(tmpstr);          
}
```

in this trace you'll see if the streams' metadata has items like:
seekpoints:93:offset = 10342550
seekpoints:93:time = 165.799
or maybe:
keyframes:times = 0,0.48,0.96,1.44,1.92,2.4,2.88,3.36,3.84,4.32,4.8,5.28,5.76,6.24
keyframes:filepositions = 1063,95174,136998,176043,209542,239148,271062,302006,331724,363948,395039,427503,456317,483313
it depends on encoder settings, if your metadata has any object of this kind (`metadata['keyframes']`, `metadata['seekpoints']` etc) you can do the following:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < metaInfo['keyframes']['times'].length; i++) {
    if (stream.time < metaInfo['keyframes']['times'][i]) {
        var keyFrameNum: int = (metaInfo['keyframes']['times'][i] - stream.time < stream.time - metaInfo['keyframes']['times'][i - 1]) ? i : i - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a static class to parse netstream metadata object to as3 object. You can use JSON.stringify(parse(info)) to check all attribute in info. This class just draftly implement. May be some bugs inside.

```
public class NetStreamMetaData
{
    public static function parse(object:Object, isArray:Boolean = false):Object{
        var ret:Object = {};
        if(isArray)
            ret = [];

        var k:String;
        for(k in object){
            if(isNaN(Number(k))){
                if(object[k] is Array){
                    ret[k] = parse(object[k], true);
                }else{
                    ret[k] = object[k];
                }   
            }else{
                if(object[k] is Array){
                    ret.push(parse(object[k], false));
                }else{
                    ret.push(object[k]);
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```